# Is there any way to Filter a Sub Grid Dynamically in Model Driven App

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I am having Sub-Grid in a Form where, I need to filter a Column as per the data from other feild of a table. I have been trying to achieve this using Java Script but not sure getting the error an "undefined". Tried out many way but nothing has helped.

```
var conSubGrid = Xrm.Page.getControl("Subgrid_new_9");
conSubGrid.setFilterXml("<filter><condition attribute=’cr85c_Nameid’ operator=’eq’ 
value=’ABCD’ /></filter>");
conSubGrid.refresh();
```

I am able to fetch the Current Grid Details but not able to Set the filter Criteria.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that setFilterXml is an undocumented javascript api for subgrid so there might be possible deprecation or removal of this api in future.

As per the samples avaialable in other forums you have to pass the whole fetchXML in the setFilterXml and not just the filterxml.

> Update: modified below function to get fetchXml and modify to append
> the filterxml and setFetchXml & Refresh

```
function SubGridFilterExecution(executionContext) {

    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

    var gridContext = formContext.getControl("Subgrid_new_9");

    var fetchXml = gridContext.getFetchXml();

    fetchXml = fetchXml.replace("</entity>", "<filter><condition attribute='cr85c_Nameid' operator='eq' value='ABCD' /></filter></entity>");

    gridContext.setFilterXml(fetchXml);

    gridContext.refresh();
}
```

https://www.crmcrate.com/javascript/dynamics-365-crm-filter-the-sub-grid-dynamically-with-javascript/

Comment: hi @harinarayanan,, thanks for the quick response i have already gone through that URL and tried but still getting the same error as "Undefined" .

Comment: Could you provide the code being used? I can see that you are using Xrm.Page which should not be the case.

Comment: var gridContext = Xrm.Page.getControl("cc_1686807734093");
var fetchXml = gridContext.getFetchXml();
fetchXml = fetchXml.replace("</entity>", "<filter><condition attribute='khv_candidatename' operator='eq' value='Harsha' /></filter></entity>");
gridContext.setFilterXml(fetchXml);
gridContext.refresh();
That is allow to add the excutioncontext and getting the error as "VM7165:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: executionContext is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:19"

Comment: Where is this JavaScript being invoked (Button, Form, field change, Web resource)? If you are ok Dataverse Xrm.Page.getControl is deprecated & unsupported, code should be using formContext instead.

Comment: when we try run the code in Inspect mode that is working trying and create that as script on the page load even then that must work

var gridContext = formContext.getControl("<<Your gird Name>>");
var fetchXml = gridContext.getFetchXml();

Comment: Can you post your whole javascript? And also how u configured the onload?